# Creating a new file based on three .tsv files in unix

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal

I have three very large files and I just want to grab the matching ID2s that come up for the first 20 ID2s for file 1 (in the example, I listed only 5). I want it to search file 2 and file 3 in its entirety and pull out the lines that match to the 20 ID2s from file1. I also want the ID1- even if it's blank (as well as other columns that are on the same matching ID2 line).

I know how to do this in python, but since the files are so large, my computer can't handle it. I have been trying to do it in the terminal (unix) with no luck.
I tried the following command but 1)it doesn't deal with three files and 2) it is also throwing me an error (maybe I'm grabbing the wrong columns)?

```
awk ‘NR==FNR{a[$1][$0];next} $0 in a {for (i in a[$0]) print i}’ file1.tsv file2.tsv
```

Error:

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

Another question:
How do I skip the first five rows in unix when doing the command (because these files have some notes in the beginning that are read in as rows)?

```
file1 
     id 1             id2          name
    A00000004   B00000004          emily    
                B00000005          joe      
    A00000006   B00000006          jack     
                B00000007          john
    A00000008   B00000008          sally    

file2
    id1             id2     source    source_code
    A00000001   B00000001   source1    321
    A00000003   B00000003   source2    165
    A00000004   B00000004   source3    481
    A00000005   B00000005   source2    891

file 3
      id2         code
    B00000006    yes    
    B00000007    no     
    B00000005    yes        
    B00000004    yes
    B00000012    yes
```

```
Desired: 
    id1             id2     name      source    source_code    code
    A00000004   B00000004    emily     source3    481          yes
    A00000005   B00000005    joe       source2    891          yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to start on the Nth line of a file:

`tail -n +N infile`

To match the `id2` columns in the different files, I'd recommend the `join` command. However, there are drawbacks, including the requirement to know which columns contain `id2` and the need to sort on those columns. This method also won't recognize more than one identical column (e.g. the `id1` column will be repeated for each file in which it appears). It's also unclear to me from the question if there are headers you want to keep. This method will lose the headers.

```
# Sort files on the id2 column
# First, drop the header line.
# Then sort on the common column (in this case the 2nd field).
# "-t $'\t'" means to use tabs as the field separator. 
tail -n +2 file1 | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2 > file1.sort
tail -n +2 file2 | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2 > file2.sort
tail -n +2 file3 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 > file3.sort
```

First join `file1.sort` to `file2.sort`:

```
# The "-j 2" flag means that both files use the second column as the common field.
# One could also use "-1 2 -2 2" to specify the field for the first and second files. 
join -t $'\t' -j 2 file1.sort file2.sort > file1-2
```

Then join that file to `file3.sort`. Note that the output of `join` places the joined column first, by default.

```
join -t $'\t' -j 1 file1-2 file3.sort > files1-3
```

You can save a step, and an intermediary file, by combining the last two commands:

```
join -t $'\t' -j 2 file1.sort file2.sort | join -t $'\t' -j 1 - file3.sort > files1-3
```

```
>cat files1-3
B00000004   A00000004   emily   A00000004   source3 481 yes
B00000005       joe A00000005   source2 891 yes
```

---

If you know that the columns are arranged the way they are in the example, you can also use `join`'s output formatting to clean things up a bit:

```
join -t $'\t' -j 2 file1.sort file2.sort | join -t $'\t' -j 1 -o 1.4,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.6,2.2 - file3.sort > files1-3_format
```

```
>cat files1-3_format
A00000004   B00000004   emily   source3 481 yes
A00000005   B00000005   joe source2 891 yes
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I got this error when I ran the first line for file1 `sort: $‘t’: Invalid argument`. Also, is it possible to sort something even though it has a prefix? For example the column having a prefix of "user0001"?

Comment: The command ``` sort -t $'\t' ``` is telling the sort command to use a tab as the field delimiter. Be sure you've wrapped the \t in single quotes. This syntax should work in the bash shell. If you have reason to believe you're using a different shell for the command line, there may be different syntax. If you can't get it working, a work-around would be to substitute all the tabs for a different character and proceed from there (just be sure it's a character that doesn't already appear in your file).

Comment: By default things are sorted alphabetically, so as long as the prefix is consistent between files, it should be fine. Note, though, that "user0001", "user01", "0001", and "1" are all different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! One more question can you explain this line here-- how can i edit it to make it more relevant for my dfs?: ```join -t $'\t' -j 2 file1.sort file2.sort | join -t $'\t' -j 1 -o 1.4,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.6,2.2 - file3.sort > files1-3_format```

Comment: Also, creating the file1-2 worked, but the file1-3 is empty. I'm confused why this might be happening. How do I make sure that the file3.tsv is in the right format besides using head?

Comment: The first part of that command, before the pipe(|), is joining files 1 and 2 together. The pipe sends that output to to the next portion, rather than saving it. The second half takes the output from the first half and joins it with file 3. -j 1 means to use the first field as the join column, the -o and string of digits specifies the order to output the columns. The - in front of file3.sort means to use the incoming data as the first file, rather than a real file. run the command "man join" for more info.